# Ошибка при использовании pipeline в Python 3

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, shell

main.py:

```
print("2+2")
```

bash:

```
$ python3.5 main.py | echo
```

Error:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

В чем проблема?

С тем же bc или wc скрипт работает:

```
$ python3.5 main.py | bc
4
$ python3.5 main.py | wc
      1       1       4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

насколько я понимаю, никакой «проблемы» здесь нет. по крайней мере с программой *python*.

при выполнении «составной» команды `команда1 | команда2` оболочка создаёт два процесса — один для выполнения *команды1*, второй для выполнения *команды2*, а *stdout* первого процесса связывает «трубой» (pipe, pipeline) с *stdin* второго процесса.

если второй процесс завершается раньше, чем первый, то для первого процесса «труба» получается «поломанной» (broken pipe).

---

в вашем случае именно так и происходит: программа (либо встроенная функция) *echo* «вообще не интересуется» содержимым своего *stdin*, выводит в свой *stdout* пустую строку и завершается. а программа *python*, пройдя «долгую и мучительную» (в сравнении с *echo*) процедуру загрузки, наконец обнаруживает, что «труба-то сломана». о чём вам и сообщает. это сообщение она выдаёт в *stderr*, который ни с какими «трубами» не связан (а направляется непосредственно в псевдо-терминал, созданный оболочкой), и потому данное сообщение благополучно добирается до ваших глаз.

Comment: лёгкий способ воспроизвести ошибку: `python -c "print('a')" | :`. Хотя можно ожидать (ошибочно), что `python` процесс будет убит `SIGPIPE` сигналом до того как `BrokenPipeError` будет замечено (как это происходит с большинством утилит командной строки). Если восстановить обработчик сигнала по умолчанию, то ошибка ожидаемо не печатается:  `python -c "from signal import *; signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL); print('a')" | :` Схожая проблема: ['yes' reporting error with subprocess communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22077881/4279)

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение.